# Obtaining the value of a key inside a dictionary

Tags: tcl

I currently have something like this

```
(Desktop) 1 % dict set mymap keyA "KeyA value"
keyA {KeyA value}
(Desktop) 2 % dict set mymap keyB "KeyB value"
keyA {KeyA value} keyB {KeyB value}
(Desktop) 3 % dict get $mymap keyB
KeyB value
(Desktop) 4 % dict set mymap keyC {KeyD "keyD Value"}
keyA {KeyA value} keyB {KeyB value} keyC {KeyD "keyD Value"}
(Desktop) 5 % dict get $mymap keyC.keyD
key "keyC.keyD" not known in dictionary
```

The keyC basically contains another dictionary. That dictionary has  a key called keyD with a value "KeyD Value" . How can i obtain the value of the keyD ? I tried `keyC.keyD`

Update :

The reason I need this is because I have something like this

```
(Desktop) 20 % puts $mymap

{$schema} http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema# title Product description {A product from Acme's catalog} type object properties {id {description {The unique identifier for a product} type integer}} required id
```

And I require the value of description from within id. The above is a json object converted to a dictionary

Comment: `dict get $mymap properties id description`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the keys one after each other as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm#M13):

```
dict get $mymap keyC KeyD
```

But do be careful about the case, `keyD` and `KeyD` are not the same thing.

Comment: @Rajeshwar Just type in the required keys? There's nothing simpler.